# Pygame quitting unexpectedly (MacOS problem)

Tags: python, pygame, screen

on my mac I ran pygame and never got it working and I've done my research and found no conclusion.

The code I used to bring up some sort of screen...

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((400,400))
pygame.display.set_caption("My first game")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

run = True
while run:

    # handle events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             run = False

    # update game objects
    # [...]

# clear display
win.fill((0, 0, 0))

# draw game objects
# [...]

# update display
pygame.display.flip()

# limit frames per second
clock.tick(60) 

pygame.quit()
```

The python launcher logo jumps up and down for a second
and comes up with python quit unexepctedly

```
Process:               Python [4082]
Path:                  /Library/Frameworks   
/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/Resources/Python.app
/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:            org.python.python
Version:               3.9.5 (3.9.5)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        Python [4040]
Responsible:           Python [4082]
User ID:               505
```

Any help on how I can get pygame to work?
Or how to get any screen at all?

btw i installed pygame with pip3
and pip

Comment: Where is your application loop?

Comment: @Rabbid76 tried that still quits unexpectedly

Comment: So the problem is with your system, but not with your code.

Comment: Read [Installing PyGame on a Mac OS](https://www.youngwonks.com/blog/How-to-Install-PyGame-on-a-Mac)

Answer (score 0):

You aren't telling pygame to run any events, and so the window just closes and the program stops.

Comment: how do i do this?

Comment: the problem is still there check my code above to help

Comment: The program works on my OS, so it is most probably something wrong with MacOS. Have you tried other code with pygame, and did you run other projects with pygame?

Comment: yes the official examples too and the same problem came up